# "hide" an installed android app

Tags: android, installation, apk

Is there a way to "hide" an installed android app from showing up under App> Installed/ Downloaded/ On SD Card

Or is there a way to limit other applications access to your app?

Im trying to negate APKInstaller to access "see" my app, to prevent it from allowing the "export" function under APKInstaller "manage" option which allows for my app to be exported to .apk

Thnx...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to "hide" an installed android app from showing up under App> Installed/ Downloaded/ On SD Card

Only by building your own custom ROM.

> Or is there a way to limit other applications access to your app?

That depends on the nature of the "access".

> Im trying to negate APKInstaller to my access "see" my app, to prevent it from allowing the "export" function under APKInstaller "manage" option which allows for my app to be exported to .apk

No, sorry, most APK files are world-readable.

Comment: Thnx for the reply.

`That depends on the nature of the "access".`

Acess defined as APKInstaller being able to see and export my app to .APK

Im not entirely sure I understand why an installed app, can be exported and repackaged as an .apk

Comment: @user1446988: As I noted, most APK files are world-readable; APKInstaller is merely copying them, in all likelihood.

Comment: Right..maybe Im mis-understand, there is no difference between a installed App, even at the system /ROM level and an .apk. 

APKinstaller is grabbing the APP (no the .apk file)exporting it and repackaging it as an .apk

Comment: @user1446988: The APK that the user obtained from wherever (e.g., Play Store) is kept untouched on the device. Certain portions of that file may *also* be unpacked from the APK for faster access (e.g., Dalvik bytecode in `classes.dx`). "APKinstaller is grabbing the APP (no the .apk file)" -- the APP *is* the APK file. Moreover, [APKInstaller](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.graphilos.apkinst&hl=en) *installs apps* -- it does not export and/or repackage anything.

Comment: Hmm ok so the app is the .apk. Perhaps Im mis-using the term export or repackage.What Im referring to is APKInstaller has an option under "Manage" that allows user to "export" the app to an .apk, which can then be transferred and re-installed on any device

Comment: err..n/m character count wont let me post the manager.java I got by exporting APKInstaller it self and dexing the .apk